# Nexus 上のリンク URL を正しく curl するには？

Tags: unix, curl, sonatype-nexus

nexus 上の welcome 画面から、 artifact を検索して、リンクアドレスをコピーすると、たとえば次のような url を取得します。
(具体例として、 sonatype (https://repository.sonatype.org) で elasticsearch の artifact を取得するケースを想定。)

```
https://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=central-proxy&g=org.elasticsearch&a=elasticsearch&v=2.2.1&e=jar
```

この url に対して、curl を実行したところ、次のテキストファイルがダウンロードされました。
(実行コマンド: `curl -o elasticsearch.jar "$URL"`)

```
If you are not automatically redirected use this url: https://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/central-proxy/content/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/2.2.1/elasticsearch-2.2.1.jar
```

リダイレクトが正しく解決できていないように見受けられます。

質問:

- 正しく curl (wget でもいいのですが) でこの nexus 上の成果物を取得する方法はありますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-L`あるいは`--location`オプションでリダイレクトを追跡します。

```
curl -L 'https://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=central-proxy&g=org.elasticsearch&a=elasticsearch&v=2.2.1&e=jar'
```